# Can recyclerView have the last row with custom item that does not same with the other items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a layout with order list and last row is the total price of those order. And I don't have an idea that how can I do those list items and last row with my desire custom item, together in a recycler view. Do I make some logic in onBindViewHolder? Or, does it have another way, one of the RecyclerView methods?

Comment: you can do this by getting last item position

Comment: You can use Recycler view header and footer.

Comment: Thank you @Chithra , you saved my day. I almost do some logic in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using `ItemTypes`,`RecyclerView` can render different type of child views, Please refer to this example : [RecyclerView With Multiple Item Types](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-dfba3979050)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using below code on your RecyclerAdapter class

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==(getItemCount()-1))return 1;
    else return 2;

}
```

In onCreateViewHolder inflate your last layout according to your viewType.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 1) {
        // inflate your first item layout & return that viewHolder
    } else {
        // inflate your second item layout & return that viewHolder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple relative or linear layout to display Total price of those orders.

And this layout will place below the recyclerview / Listview in XMl.

if you use above solution then you don't need to use last item of list for displaying total price of those orders.